# How to connect Altera DE2 board to Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, usb, device-manager, peripherals

I added the driver that comes with Quartus II web edition and it finds the card:
[image]

And the card appears in the device manager so it indeed looks correct so far.
[image]

But when I start Quartus Programmer to download my logic to the board, the hardware part of the interface is bland where I expect to see my card:
[image]

What can be done? The instructions I have are available [here](http://www.ict.kth.se/courses/IS1500/2012/swsetup/de2run.html).

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same situation here - I had to revert to 11.1sp2, and then it worked for me.

Comment: @kinokijuf This post provides a solution to the problem, I don't see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It finally worked for me too, but in a random way. At some point the board just started appearing in the programmer window, so everything was fine at the end.

Comment: With 13.0 this has been fixed.